# display the result in header for only particular phtml page

Tags: phtml, header

on a particular phtml page, we added following code :

```
<img src="/32-32.jpg" alt="Customer care" /><span> 99999999 </span>

<span>welcome &nbsp;</span>
 <a title="Sign Out Your Account Here.." href="https://sitename.com/customer/account/logout/">Sign Out</a>
```

and its displaying like this, code is reflecting below horizontal line, above horizontal line you can see logo in rectangle shape.

[image]

i want to reflect code above horizontal line, means in header.

and it should reflect only in particular phtml page. when i tried through css, it did't worked for me

Comment: Add different header for that page in local.xml

Comment: @Kothari post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

add your `local.xml` Create phtml and customized based on what you want and call below `xml`

```
<body_class>
       <reference name="header"> 
            <block type="page/header" name="header">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>Filepath.html</template></action> 
            </block>
        </reference>

<body_class>
```